# Using 'for loops' to run a series of linear regressions in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that consists of 2000 rows and three columns. The columns are for Subject ID #, IV, and DV. There are 50 participants in the data (Subject #s 1:50), each with 40 separate observations (so 40 rows per participant).

I'd like to find the intercept and slope for each of the individual participants, but rather than manually running 50 lm's, I'm trying to figure out a way to accomplish this using a for loop.

To keep things simple, here's a condensed version of the data (I'm just doing 5 rows for 3 participants, rather than producing the full 2000 rows).

Having no idea what I'm doing when it comes to for loops, this is the last thing I tried.

**Note:** I've recreated a smaller version of the data below. Basically I'd like to make a for loop that runs an lm of the dv on the iv for each of the four participants in the example data frame, so that I can find the intercept and slope for each individual participant (rather than aggregating everything).

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:4, each=5),
  iv = c(5.0, 3.6, 3.4, 4.5, 4.6, 7.8, 7.2, 10.8, 7.7, 8.7, 7.6, 6.8, 
         6.2, 5.6, 4.6, 6.7, 6.6, 6.3, 7.0, 5.1),
  dv = c(6.50, 8.50, 8.00, 10.00, 10.00, 3.50, 10.00, 7.25, 2.50, 6.50,
         10.00, 8.75, 10.00, 9.75, 10.00, 7.75, 7.75, 7.50, 8.75, 5.75)  
)


for (i in 1:4)
{
  m3 <- lm(df$dv ~ df$iv, data=df$id[[i]])
}
```

Comment: Create a reprex and post your data using `dput()` and show us the code  you have tried so far.

Comment: toefer, we're not going to read your mind or infer your data or solve your entire problem for you. Please consider taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's important to learn how to ask a question well because (a) if you are able to do it well, you are more likely to get an answer here; (b) if not, you will be frustrated by down-votes and not-helpful comments.

Comment: Thanks guys, I've updated the post to hopefully be more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Not a for-loop but definitely a more concise R-centric way of going about things. `broom::tidy()` just takes the output from `lm()` and puts it into an easy to handle data frame.

EDIT: If you want it in one data.frame and be able to distinguish across ID's you can use the updated code below. I believe `do()` is deprecated or no longer the supported method to manipulate functions.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

df <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:4, each=5),
  iv = c(5.0, 3.6, 3.4, 4.5, 4.6, 7.8, 7.2, 10.8, 7.7, 8.7, 7.6, 6.8, 
         6.2, 5.6, 4.6, 6.7, 6.6, 6.3, 7.0, 5.1),
  dv = c(6.50, 8.50, 8.00, 10.00, 10.00, 3.50, 10.00, 7.25, 2.50, 6.50,
         10.00, 8.75, 10.00, 9.75, 10.00, 7.75, 7.75, 7.50, 8.75, 5.75)  
)

df %>% 
  group_split(id) %>% 
  map_df(~ lm(dv ~ iv, data = .) %>% 
           tidy() %>% 
           mutate(id = unique(.x$id))
         )
#> # A tibble: 8 x 6
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic p.value    id
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <int>
#> 1 (Intercept)   8.96       5.28     1.70   0.188       1
#> 2 iv           -0.0847     1.24    -0.0684 0.950       1
#> 3 (Intercept)   3.55      10.3      0.344  0.753       2
#> 4 iv            0.284      1.21     0.235  0.829       2
#> 5 (Intercept)  10.5        1.65     6.36   0.00786     3
#> 6 iv           -0.126      0.264   -0.478  0.665       3
#> 7 (Intercept)  -1.69       1.06    -1.59   0.210       4
#> 8 iv            1.45       0.167    8.69   0.00321     4
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I approach this kind of grouped regression by combining `group_by()` and `do()`.

While @dylanjm has provided a nice concise method using `map()` and `broom()` to produce a list of tibbles containing model outputs, this alternative might be handy if you want a single df with two columns listing all of your intercepts & slopes.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(id = rep(1:4, each=5),
             iv = c(5.0, 3.6, 3.4, 4.5, 4.6, 7.8, 7.2, 10.8, 7.7, 8.7, 7.6, 6.8, 
                    6.2, 5.6, 4.6, 6.7, 6.6, 6.3, 7.0, 5.1),
             dv = c(6.50, 8.50, 8.00, 10.00, 10.00, 3.50, 10.00, 7.25, 2.50, 6.50,
                    10.00, 8.75, 10.00, 9.75, 10.00, 7.75, 7.75, 7.50, 8.75, 5.75)) 

#This will segment obs by the `id` variable, & run a separate lm for each of the segments.
df_lms<- df %>% 
         group_by(id)%>% 
         do(mod = lm(dv ~ iv, data=.))

#This will give you a dataframe with a column for intercepts, and a column for slopes.
cbind(df_lms %>% do(data.frame(intc = coef(.$mod)[1])),
      df_lms %>% do(data.frame(slope = coef(.$mod)[2])))
```